# what is inside skipped memory address?

Tags: c++, memory

We know integer variable take 4-byte memory address. I just wonder, if we initialize integer variables and make a pointer to it. I can get the value of it from the pointer (which have the address of the variable: `0x22fef8` in my computer). But how about the memory address after `0x22fef8` which is `0x22fef9`, `0x22fefa`, `0x22fefb`? What is in there? Are we will get the value of the variable if we dereference this address? How to access them?

Comment: If an integer takes four bytes, then those four bytes contain the integer. What's the mystery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right: in a 32-bit computer an integer takes up four bytes. In C, that can be expressed by the following code:

```
int i = 0x12345678;
int *p_i = &i;`
```

If `p_i` gets the value `0x22fef8`, then `p_i++` would become `0x22fefc` since it would point to the next integer. If you want to see what's in the bytes that make up `i`, you need to use a different pointer:

```
typedef uint_8 byte;
byte *p_b = (byte *)&i;`
```

That means that you change the pointer-to-int that `&i` represents and typecast it to be a pointer-to-byte. It will still have the value `0x22fef8` since that's where the first byte of `i` is - but now if you do a `p_b++` it will change to `0x22fef9`. And note that if you print out the original value of `*p_b` (that is, the byte that it is pointing to), it will not give the same value as `i`. Depending on the computer, it will print out either the first byte or the last byte: `0x12` or `0x78`, or at least the decimal versions thereof.

This is due to the "endianness" of the computer, which affects the storage of multi-byte values. Little-endian computers like the x86 store the littlest part of the value first - the `0x78` - while Power PC computers store the biggest part of the value first - the `0x12`.

Comment: so inside 3 bytes after 0x22fef8 is piece of the variable and it depend by specification of computer which part to store first?

Comment: @Aorstab That is exactly right. If the 4-byte integer _0x12345678_ was stored at _0x22ef8_-_0x22efb_, then on the `x86` the `0x78` would be stored at `0x22ef8`, then the `0x56` at `0x22ef9` etc. On a `PowerPC`, the `0x12` would be stored at `0x22ef8`, then the `0x34` at `0x22ef9` etc.

Answer (score 1):

`int` types take up four bytes *on your system*, so those are all occupied by the `int`. All are inaccessible except the first one.

It is to note some `int`s take up two bytes on other systems. It isn't regulated by the standard.

Comment: What do you mean by "inaccessible"? Certainly you can access those bytes.

Comment: not with an `int*`, which is what I meant, and wasn't really constructive, anyway. @tuple_cat

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the values in those addresses, just do this and you will get values of next 10 addresses

```
int main()
{
  int a = 5;
  int *p_i = &a; // The address of 'a' is stored in pointer 'p_i'

  // Now you want to check the values in 10 further addresses 

  for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
  {
    int value = *p_i;  // Here it is getting the address of pointer as integer value
    cout << value << endl;
    p_i++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```